# In-graph replication vs Between-graph replication

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to understand the differences betweens **In-graph replication** and **Between-graph replication** described in [distributed tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/how_tos/distributed/index.html), specially on how the data is being synced between multiple devices.

My understanding is that in **in-graph replication**, each worker does NOT keep a replica of the model locally, which seems to be the main difference with **between-graph replication**.

Therefore, for **in-graph replication**, each input tensor to each operation will be a connection to where the Variable has been stored (probably on a different Parameter Server machine). While in **between-graph replication**, data is being pulled in *batch* to sync all the parameters.

Am I right on this interpretation?
Does this mean that for each operation in in-graph replication the data is being pulled from PS?
Is this pulling *sync* or *async*?

Comment: We have the similar question so I ask in Google Group, checkout it out https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/tensorflow/yQgXrm7QqDM

Comment: personally, I found this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41600321/distributed-tensorflow-the-difference-between-in-graph-replication-and-between) really helpful!