# Does tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer do complete parameter update from aggregated gradients to value for many times?

Tags: python, tensorflow, distributed

In `/model/inception/inception/inception_distributed_training.py` apply_gradients are called for each worker.

```
apply_gradients_op = opt.apply_gradients(grads, global_step=global_step)
```

and go into SyncReplicasOptimizer.py:

```
  285       # sync_op will be assigned to the same device as the global step.
  286       with ops.device(global_step.device), ops.name_scope(""):
  287         update_op = self._opt.apply_gradients(aggregated_grads_and_vars,
  288                                               global_step)
  289
```

line 287 are will be executed by each worker process at ps device.

I think, even the job that aggregating all replicas gradients only works for one time, but once aggregating job finished, all replicas will rpc calls remote apply_gradients operations group to generate next variable value. If that's real, the duplicated apply_gradients can be eliminated by checking is_chief flag.

By the way two more questions:

- How to control the exclusive variable buffer access if multiple updating operations come?
- Can we use "caching_device" flag to eliminate multiple remote variable access (multiple network communication procedure) ? if that's ok, how to trigger update(invalid) cached variable if variables on ps are updated?

I have carefully read lots of documents and done lots of experiments to verify it, but official answer could be highly appreciated again.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to answer it by myself after carefully and carefully review these code snippets.

```

```
  310       with ops.device(global_step.device), ops.name_scope(""):
  311         # Replicas have to wait until they can get a token from the token queue.
  312         with ops.control_dependencies(train_ops):
  313           token = sync_token_queue.dequeue()
  314         train_op = state_ops.assign(self._local_step, token)
  315
  316         with ops.control_dependencies([update_op]):
  317           # Sync_op needs to insert tokens to the token queue at the end of the
  318           # step so the replicas can fetch them to start the next step.
  319           tokens = array_ops.fill([self._tokens_per_step], global_step)
  320           sync_op = sync_token_queue.enqueue_many((tokens,))
  321
  322         if self._variable_averages is not None:
  323           with ops.control_dependencies([sync_op]), ops.name_scope(""):
  324             sync_op = self._variable_averages.apply(
  325                 self._variables_to_average)
  326
  327         self._chief_queue_runner = queue_runner.QueueRunner(dummy_queue,
  328                                                             [sync_op])
```

```

There two ops set, train_ops and update_op. update_op  ends up with sync_op. the 'sync_op' will be executed by QueueRunner return as self._chief_queue_runner. The train_ops is end up with  train_op called at the context of each worker.

As a brief conclusion, sync_op are returned for the chief worker to do parameter updating(done by all ps, in reality, the chief worker just do control synchronisation mechanism). train_op are called by each worker.

That's the updating action only works one time, no duplicated updating.

That's all.

Comment: Who can give more about caching_device internals, especially under cross devices scene?