# tf.train.replica_device_setter needed with tf.contrib.learn.Experiment?

Tags: tensorflow, distributed-computing

I built a distributed tensorflow program using `tf.estimator.Estimator`, `tf.contrib.learn.Experiment` and `tf.contrib.learn.learn_runner.run`.

For now it seems to work fine. However, the [tensorflow distributed tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed) uses `tf.train.replica_device_setter` to pin operations to jobs.

My model function does not use any `with device` annotation. Is this done automatically by the `Experiment` class or am I missing an important point?

I am further not sure, why there is a need to assign certain devices when I am using data parallism?

Thanks for any help and hints on this,
Tobias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables and ops are defined in `tf.estimator.Estimator`, which actually uses `replica_device_setter` ([defined here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py#L758)). As you can see, it assigns variables to `ps` jobs and ops to `worker` jobs, which is the common way to handle data parallelism.

`replica_device_setter` returns a device function that assigns ops and variables to devices. Even if you're using data parallelism, you might have many parameter servers, and a device function will ensure each parameter server gets separate variables (determined by `ps_strategy` of `replica_device_setter`). e.g. `/job:ps/tasks:0` could get `W1` and `b1`, and `/job:ps/tasks:1` could get `W2` and `b2`. The device function has to be deterministic in assigning variables to parameter servers, since the function is called every time a worker replica is instantiated, and the workers need to agree on which `ps` holds which variables.

tf.(contrib.)learn libraries [use between-graph replication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41601168/507062). This means that each worker replica will build a separate graph, with the non-Variable ops assigned to that worker: worker with task index 2 defines ops to `/job:worker/task:2`, and variables to `/job:ps` (which specific `ps` is determined by `ps_strategy`). This means that the worker replica will compute the ops (loss value & gradients) itself, and send the resulting variable updates (gradients) to the particular parameter servers that are responsile for holding the particular variables.

If you didn't have a mechanism to assign variables/ops to devices, it would not be clear which replica should hold which variables and ops. Assigning to specific devices might also be needed if you have several GPUs on a worker replica: even though your variables are stored on parameter servers, you would need to create the compute-intensive part of the graph once for each of your GPUs (with explicitly assigning the created ops to the relevant GPU).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer,@mattias !
Just to clarify: tf.(contrib).learn libraries handle the device assignment for me. But if I have special assignments (e.g. model parallism, several gpus etc) than I need to explicitly assign the devices myself? Did I get that right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. If the above answered your question, please upvote :)